# How to use existing controllers defined in my Angular app inside AngularMaterials mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

so my issue is this, i have controllers already defined as

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')
 .controller('Test1Ctrl', function(){ ...
 .controller('Test2Ctrl', function(){ ...
 .controller('SettingsCtrl', function(){ ...
```

Now I want to add the `$mdDialog` inside `Test2Ctrl`, problem is - I want to pass to its `controller:` - an actual controller that I already defined above ( test1/test2/Settings etc .. )

But it seems as all the examples out-there - including AngularMaterials, are all creating some sub-function called `FunctionCtrl` - and use it - as a controller ?!

So what happens if I do use: `controller: 'SettingsCtrl',` - it throw an AngularJS error that Angular was loaded more than once ... and I see my entire site in small inside the dialog box :)

This is the examples I see out-there - and instead of `controller: 'DialogCtrl',` - I want to use `SettingsCtrl` or at least the functionality inside it, I don't want to write the code again ...

```
angular.module('starter.controllers')
    .controller('testCtrl', function(){
        $scope.click = function(message){
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'DialogCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'dialogInfo.html',
                targetEvent: ev,
                locals : {
                    message : message
                }
            })...
        }
        function DialogCtrl($scope, $mdDialog, message) {
            $scope.message = message;
        }
    );
```

Comment: I don't see that there would be any problem with referencing already defined controller. Could you share your real code snippet of how you are defining the controller and how you are using it in your modal?

Comment: You will need a separate controller for `md-dialog` but you can pass data from your parent controller to this new dialog controller.

Comment: @Gaurav it's the same as I wrote above ( can't share entire code but it's really not different ) ... inside `Test2Ctrl` there's a dialog that I want it to use the `SettingsCtrl` that I've written below it ...

Comment: @nextt1 would you mind sharing example ? - as said, all examples are having a new function at the bottom, I can't seems to find how to pass it any other information ( except `$scope` variables, that I know )

Comment: Here is a quick demo: http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/KWMbNY?editors=1010 and as I said I don't see any problem.

Comment: @Gaurav so your example still hold functions as controllers, I don't write like that, I've edited the codepen - in the same way I usually write http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpKjVe?editors=1010, still it works, so I'm not sure what's the problem in my case. as said, I did wrote `SettingsCtrl` and it throw error that it `Angular was loaded more than once`

Comment: `Angular was loaded more than once` could be due to a variety of reasons. Clearly, whatever that is, it's not related to `SettingsCtrl` reuse in `modal`. Try to pinpoint that error, most of the time it's related to wrong filename or URL or misplaced/erroneous tag.

Comment: @Gaurav Bingo, `Try to pinpoint that error, most of the time it's related to wrong filename or URL or misplaced/erroneous tag` - I use `templateUrl` and I thought the path is taken from the root, but I'm inside the `js/` dir, so it couldn't find it - and load the entire site instead ...:/ placing your snippet as `template` vs `templateUrl` helped me understand that - thank you !

Comment: @Gaurav if you want some points, place an answer - and I'll approve it

Comment: @RickyLevi I'm glad that I was of any help! Some points, that would be nice ;). I'll post an answer demoing the reuse of the controller and the other hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a quick demo, which showcases the re-use of the existing controller for `modal` dialog:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .controller('ModalController', ModalController);

function MyController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      clickOutsideToClose: true,

      template: '<md-dialog>' +
        '  <md-dialog-content>' +
        '     Hi There {{message}}' +
        '  </md-dialog-content>' +
        '</md-dialog>',

      controller: 'ModalController'
    });
  };
}

function ModalController($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'You are an amazing person!';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event)">
    Alert Dialog
  </md-button>

</div>
```

Note: Regarding `Angular was loaded more than once` could be due to a variety of reasons. Clearly, whatever that is, it's not related to `SettingsCtrl` reuse in `modal` dialog. Try to pinpoint that error, most of the time it's related to wrong filename or wrong URL or misplaced/erroneous tag.

Comment: Yep, the `templateUrl` was the root cause of dialog trying to load the entire website & the Angular error ... fixing it - solve the entire issue.